# iOS Facebook FQL check if user has about_me filled out

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-fql

I run a fql query:

```
SELECT uid, name, pic, sex, hometown_location, about_me FROM user WHERE uid=me()
```

but some users don't have the about_me filled out, how do I check if it has a value?  When I call:

```
[aboutMe setText: [result objectForKey:@"about_me"]];
```

I get an error if the user does not have their about_me filled out.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem - Facebook's User Graph uses the name "bio" not "about_me" to hold the user's description now - try that.